# How to deploy anything to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Literally, I'm not even able to deploy sample app with all default options. I tried to deploy sample app with eb. I have initialised it, created it and it returned me 503. error was:

```
Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Warning. Initialization completed 28 seconds ago and took 3 minutes. There are no instances. Unable to assume role "arn:aws:iam::<number>:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role". Verify that the role exists and is configured correctly.
```

This role exists, and was created previously.

I also tried to run it sample app manually.

```
Successfully launched environment:
```

However its state is pending and when I try to enter DNS "no internet".

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of deploying a Java web app to Elastic Beanstalk and it works. The web app is basically a web form built with Spring Boot. On the back it, it uses a few AWS Services such as Amazon DynamoDB to store submitted data.

It then describes how to bundle the web app into a FAT JAR and then deploy it the app to Elastic Beanstalk. This is located in the [AWS Code Catelog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). See:

[Build an application to submit data to a DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_SubmitDataApp_java_2_topic.html)

Comment: But I’m interested in docker app.

Comment: If you are interested in deploying a web app to a container, then look at using ECS and Fargate, A blog is here that shows how to deploy the same Java WEB app as above to a container. See https://scottscloudcommunity.blogspot.com/2022/10/deploying-java-web-application-to.html

Comment: SO i have shown you 2 ways to deploy an example web app - 1 - use Elastic Beanstalk 2 - use Fargate.